# Why does TAWS alert depends on airspeed?

Tags: landing, approach

According to the TSO 151c:

> Speed. Airspeed or groundspeed must be included in the logic that determines basic
>   GPWS alerting time for “excessive closure rate to terrain” and “flight into terrain when not in
>   landing configuration” to allow maximum time for the flight crew to react and take corrective
>   action.

As I understand for "flight into terrain when not in landing configuration" modes, in the guides corner speeds are given as from 190 KTS to 250 KTS. I can understand the calculations dependency on airspeed but do you have any idea how these speeds are selected? Are they regulated by FAA or EASA? As far as i know,

> §91.117   Aircraft speed.
>   (a) Unless otherwise authorized by the Administrator, no person may operate an aircraft below 10,000 feet MSL at an indicated airspeed of more than 250 knots (288 m.p.h.).

but why 190 KTS? Is there any speed limits that should be obeyed for approaches and landing?

Comment: are we speaking of a specific aircraft model? where do those numbers (190/250 KTS) appear?

Comment: Distance to the terrain divided by the closure speed gives you the time it will take to reach the terrain. If you are 5 minutes away you don't need a warning.

Comment: @Federico I am not speaking about a specific aircraft, guides also says it can change accorrding to the aircraft type between 190-220 knots. I wonder is there any description what should be the IAS during approach and landing.

Comment: @GdD is 5 minutes sort of a standard? I could not find it in  FLTA given in TSO151.

Comment: @tigris, it was just a number I picked out of my head.

Comment: Most TAWS or EGPWS computers give a 60 second `CAUTION TERRAIN` and a 30 second `TERRAIN, TERRAIN PULL UP` warnings.

Comment: @wbeard52: That's the matter for a good formal answer...

Comment: @wbeard52 indeed i'd like to learn what are the speed limits for approach , final approach and landing for a standard airliner aircraft, like A380 or B737? If it is said that your speed limit should be 190 knots maximum for approach and 160 knots for final approach then it is ok for me. I wonder abouut those limits.